# How to use 'git config -l' cli?

Tags: git

I found if I command `git config -l` then it showes a list like(maybe config), and now I know  I can quit the cli by `q` key, but I want to use the cli. How to use it? For example, if I want to change user.email, user.name?

Comment: Read the info which you get when doing: `git config --help` ? (or visit: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config )

Comment: The `quit` is a red herring; it's just an artifact of your pager, which has nothing to do with Git. For how to change e.g. the user name, please read the docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config

Comment: Or even https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid you wouldn't be able to easily modify config with that command. This command only list your configuration and the 'cli' you see is your pager (like `less` or `more`) which turns on only when full content cannot fit screen. You can ofc change it to some specific editor

```
git config --global core.pager "vim -"
```

And get the content but you won't be able to save it without providing full name.

The proper way to edit config is

```
git config --edit --global
```

Which will open config in your configured editor

```
git config --global core.editor vim
```